# Example for geting list of Access Permissions for a Security Group in Active Directory and not for a text file of folder

Tags: active-directory

I need an example (code snippet) of getting a list of access permissions for a security group in Active Directory and NOT for Text files/Folders in Windows XP.

Is it possible to give me a code snippet that gets **ALL** the security permissions (Read, Write, Full control) for SECURITY GROUPS E.g.: `Domain Controllers` in the `ACTIVE DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are stored on the individual file system items, e.g. files and/or directories - or other objects (like registry keys, etc.). When you have an AD group or user account, you can read it's SID (Security Identifier) property - that SID will show up in ACL's (Access Control Lists) all over Windows - but from the user or group, there's no mechanism to get all permissions it might have anywhere in the machine/server.

Permissions for files and directories can e.g. be retrieved using the .GetAccessControl() method on the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"D:\test.txt");
FileSecurity fs = info.GetAccessControl();

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\test\");
DirectorySecurity ds = dir.GetAccessControl();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. You mean to tell that the security TAB UI Permission details of the Security groups(EG:DOmain Controller")in the Active Directory cannot be get programmatically? If read/Write of Security Tab UI Permissions could be set programmatically, Is getting the All Permission details is not possible? Kindly Justify